# Magnetic force between an infinite and a finite current carrying wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

My question is simple.

> What would be the magnetic force between an infinite and a finite but obliquely placed current carrying wire?

One end of the finite wire is at a perpendicular distance $a$ from the infinite wire(see figure below). The length of the finite wire is $b$ and it carries current $I_2$. The current in the infinite wire is $I_1$.

[image: Fmag b/w two straight wires]

Note that the result for this question can be tested by putting $\theta=0^o$ and $\theta=90^o$, whose results can be evaluated without much problem using integration.

For $\theta=0^o$, the force should be 
$\vec{F}=\frac{\mu_o I_1 I_2 b}{2\pi a} (-\hat{i})$

For $\theta=90^o$, the force should be 
$\vec{F}=\frac{\mu_o I_1 I_2}{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{a+b}{a}\right) (\hat{j})$

Here $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ indicate horizontal right and vertical up directions.

Comment: Are you sure about those two limits?  If I naively think about $\mathbf{I}_{2} \times \mathbf{B}_{1}$, the force would be in the $\hat{j}$ direction, correct?  So is the direction correct for the $\theta$ = 0 case?  More importantly, should the forces not depend upon location with respect to the sources?  Or are you only interested in the force of one current-generated field upon the second current carrying particles?

Comment: @honeste_vivere I think the picture is bit misleading. $theta=0$ is usual case two parallel current carrying wires. btw after posting the question, I have tried to match the limits and got them. I am just hoping someone will tell something more.